# Unable to view WCF Mex EndPoints output in Web Browser

Tags: wcf

I am new to WCF and trying to understand Mex endpoints. I have created a testservice. Its working fine and I am able to view WSDL output from URL= "http://myweb.com:8000/testservice" as well using "URL" or "URL?wsdl".

However, I am getting 400 Bad request while browsing "URL/mex" in browser. I set httpGetEnabled="false" and then I am also able generate proxy class using svcutil as well.

Could you please advise why I am not able to veiw mex endpoint output in web browser. Below is the config file:

**App.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="HelloTest.testservice" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviour">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="HelloTest.Itestservice" address="HelloTest">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" address="mex">
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://myweb.com:8000/testservice"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"></serviceMetadata>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The UR is not accessible. Is it a local URL?

Comment: yes, its my local machine

Comment: Just for clarification, the URL "http://myweb.com:8000/testservice/mex" gives you the 400 response?

Comment: yes, but page is blank. when i do F12 in chrome the i see 400 Bad request but http://myweb.com:8000/testservice or http://myweb.com:8000/testservice?wsdl works fine